# MYSQL Records Fetch for 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i require that if time is before noon for current day, then it should take the  item_2 value of prev day for current day only. for others it will take, their proper values.

```
    id  |   item_1 | item_2 | date
    1       205         3       2015-04-07
    2       215         35      2015-04-06
    3       225         15      2015-04-05
    4       235         315     2015-04-04
```

Expected result wen time is before noon

```
    id  |   item_1 | item_2 |   sum |    date
    1       205         35      240     2015-04-07
    2       215         35      250     2015-04-06
    3       225         15      240     2015-04-05
    4       235         31      266     2015-04-04
```

Expected result wen time is after noon

```
    id  |   item_1 | item_2 |   sum |    date
    1       205         3       208     2015-04-07
    2       215         35      250     2015-04-06
    3       225         15      240     2015-04-05
    4       235         31      266     2015-04-04
```

Date and time can be used from php and how to manage for prev and current day record in same query. i tried with sub query, but i think it can be done in other way also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, next one is after noon. i edited the question.

Comment: you want `item_2` to be `UPDATE` as per your noon condition or you just want `SELECT`

Comment: @MySQLRockstar, only select for now.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use **CASE** in your query:

try this:

```
SET @time := 'BFNOON';
SET @date := '2015-04-07 00:00:00';

SELECT id, item_1, item_2, (item_1 + item_2) AS sum_item, dates FROM (
SELECT id, item_1,
(CASE
WHEN (@time = 'BFNOON' AND dates = @date) THEN 
(
SELECT item_2 FROM records WHERE dates < @date ORDER BY dates DESC  LIMIT 1
) ELSE 
item_2
END ) item_2
, dates 

FROM records ) records
```

Note: remove declaration and
replace @time = 'BFNOON' to check before or after noon
and @date with your date value of today

here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5dbe/10) as example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5dbe/10

Comment: thanks for reply, but i have lakhs of records for one user. Using sub query will make it some what heavier (i think). also, i can get with sub query , but can i do the same functionality without using the sub-query.

Comment: i think the sub-query only run when the condition match. in this case it will run only one time where record in current days. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: yes, you are correct. it will only run one time only. but still it will fetch from lakhs of records. Anyway, i am more concern, that if i can do it in one query, with out using the sub query.